# Getting "The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver." while invoking request xml

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

I have re-created and deployed simple Axis 2 webservice using Top down approach (see below) many times in Apache Tomcat server. But, I've been unable to get this simple webservice app to work!

That is, when I submit the simple SOAP request (see "service request", below) I receive the following error: "The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver."

QUESTION: What is causing this error: " "? DO I need to modify wsdl SoapAction values b4 creating web service files. Please help.

Endpoint URL is : http://localhost:8080/NotifyEvt/services/EventNotifyService/

Request XML

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:even="http://veda-services/event-notify-v1-0.xsd"
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action>http://localhost:8080/event/notifyEvent</wsa:Action>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<even:enquiry-id>23232323121266</even:enquiry-id>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Error Response

```
<soapenv:Body>
   <soapenv:Fault>
      <soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Sender</soapenv:Value>
         <soapenv:Subcode>
           <soapenv:Value xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">wsa:ActionNotSupported</soapenv:Value>
        </soapenv:Subcode>
       </soapenv:Code>
       <soapenv:Reason>
        <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.</soapenv:Text>
     </soapenv:Reason>
     <soapenv:Detail>
        <wsa:ProblemAction xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
           <wsa:Action>{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/}//localhost:8080/event/notifyEventRequest</wsa:Action>
       </wsa:ProblemAction>
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you also add the request to your question? It only shows the response.

Comment: I have got wsdl file from one of the vendor and trying to create web service using Axis 2 (Top-down approach). Web services are created successfully but error response is coming when I fire request from SOAPUI.